# Sequence object with functional Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am learning functional javascript. still newbie.
I have a problem : 
**How to change this object**

```
var object = {
    "person1": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "last": "Smith"
    },
    "person2": {
        "name": "John",
        "last": "Smith"
    },
    "person3": {
        "name": "Jane",
        "last": "Smith"
    }
}
```

**into this**. (preferably with some functional style)

```
  var object = {
    "person1": {
        "no": 1, 
        "name": "Bob",
        "last": "Smith"
    },
    "person2": {
        "no": 2,
        "name": "John",
        "last": "Smith"
    },
    "person3": {
        "no": 3,
        "name": "Jane",
        "last": "Smith"
    }
}
```

My first thought is to use the object size and make array with its length

```
makeArray = function(obj){
             for (key in obj) {
               var number = [];
               if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
               number.push(size);
             }; 
             return number;
          };
```

so `myArray = makeArray(object);
   myArray = [1,2,3];    //1,2,3 instead 0,1,2`

so I get a number 1,2,3 not 0,1,2. 
but how do i push it into individual person.properties

thanks,

Comment: As what we have here isn't syntactically correct it's hard to know what you want. What's the exact goal ?

Comment: var number; is not an array .you need to initialize the array should be var number = [];

Comment: @dystroy apologize if it's not correct; what i want is to change the first var object into second var object with additional property "no"..

Comment: @unikorn thanks for your correction. i didn't realize that I miss it. so in the end i get an array, but how do I push it into the object??

Comment: what is the criteria for your indexes. what is the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the `makeArray` function work you should:

- Initialise the array outside the loop
- declare the counter in the function and initialise it outside the loop
- Push the counter only when you find a property

Code:

```
function makeArray(obj){
  var number = [], size = 0;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      size++;
      number.push(size);
    }
  } 
  return number;
}
```

If you want to set a `no` property of the objects:

```
function setNo(obj){
  var size = 0;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      size++;
      obj[key].no = size;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @vdj4y: What are object1 and object2? An object or an array? Can you please edit the question using right syntax?

Comment: @aravind sorry, andgive me some time. The case and object is self-imaginary. I didn't even test it before I type it here. but the solution is by guffa is correct. let me try to correct the question in few minutes

Comment: @vdj4y: Thank you, it helps when people come and look at this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  "person1": {
    "name": "Bob",
    "last": "Smith"
  },
  "person2": {
    "name": "John",
    "last": "Smith"
  },
  "person3": {
    "name": "Jane",
    "last": "Smith"
  }
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(v, k) {
  obj[v].no = k;
});

console.log(obj);
```